# how to translate string added dynamicaly in Qapp with Qtranslator?

Tags: qt, qtablewidget, qtranslate

i trying to created a Qt application multilanguage with Qt linguist.
I place this code in an function of my MainWindow :

```
translator.load(":/lang/English");
qApp->installTranslator(&translator);
ui->retranslateUi(this);
```

With the QTranslator  declare in my MainWindow.h and all my string i want translate enclose by tr() . But with that, all QObject added dynamicaly by the code of my MainWindow.cpp, for example the title of a QTableWidget, are not translated.
If i place an other translator in my main.cpp, all my string are translate but i must created language button in my application and so i can't place translator in main.cpp.

Do you have an idea to help me?

Thx for your answers.

Gat

Comment: Do you call installTranslator before or after setting the text from mainwindow.cpp retranslateUi retranslates only widgets generated with uic

Comment: @KamilKlimek Sorry for the code, now i use that:

translator.load(":/lang/en");
ui->retranslateUi(this);    
qApp->installTranslator(&translator);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you add a translation in your application using `qApp->installTranslator(& aTranslator)` then all the *following* calls to `QObject::tr()` (and similar functions) will look up in the translator for a translated text. So you should call `retranslateUi()` *after* `qApp->installTranslator()`. Actually you might event not call it there, you may reimplement `QWidget::changeEvent()` and intercept any `QEvent::LanguageChange` event.

```
void MainWindow::changeEvent(QEvent *e)
{
    QMainWindow::changeEvent(e);
    switch (e->type()) {
    case QEvent::LanguageChange:
        // Someone called qApp->installTranslator() with a new translation.
        // Let's update the user visible strings.

        // This function was created by uic from the Designer form.
        // It translates all user visible texts in the form.
        ui->retranslateUi(this);

        // This function must be written by you. It translates other user visible
        // texts that are not in the form. See down for an example.
        this->retranslateUi();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

`ui->retranslateUi()` just calls `QObject::tr()` for each user visible string in the ui. It is called automatically at the end of `setupUi()` and populates the form's widgets with translated text (have a look, it is defined by uic in `ui_MainWindow.h` file). You may want to take a similar approach with other user visible texts, like the title of a QTableWidget. All the strings are set in a function (named perhaps `retranslateUi()` for consistency) which is called at application starts (or, better, after the relevant widgets are created) and every time a new translations is loaded.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget * parent)
  : QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    // Creates other widgets, but do not set their user visible texts.
    tableWidget = new QTableWidget(this);
    ...
    someControl = new QLineEdit(this);
    someOtherControl = new QSpinBox(this);

    someModel = new MyModel(this);
    ...


    // Ok, *now* we set their texts.
    this->retranslateUi();
}

...

void MainWindow::retranslateUi()
{
    // This function will be called (either manually or automatically by
    // `changeEvent()`) when a new translator has installed, hence all the `tr()`
    // calls will return the right translation for the last installed language.

    QStringList labels;
    labels.append(tr("First column"));
    labels.append(tr("Second column"));
    labels.append(tr("Third column"));

    tableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(labels);

    someControl->setText(tr("Control name"));
    someOtherControl->setText(tr("Other control name"));

    // Perhaps you have a model that need to be retranslated too
    // (you need to write its `retranslateUi()` function):
    someModel->retranslateUi();

    ...
}
```

Also, please note that if you are doing something like

```
void MainWindow::someFunction()
{
    ...

    QTranslator translator;
    translator.load(":/lang/English");
    qApp->installTranslator(& translator);

    ...
}
```

as soon as that function returns the variable `translator` gets destroyed, so next time `QObject::tr()` is called the address stored with `qApp->installTranslator(& translator)` will be invalid. So you must allocate `translator` on the heap with `new` (and possibly deleting it with `delete` when you do not need it anymore). An exception is if you are doing that in `main()` before calling `QCoreApplication::exec()` since that function is blocking and will not return until application is closed.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    ...

    QTranslator translator;
    translator.load(":/lang/English");
    app.installTranslator(& translator);

    ...

    app.exec(); // This function will return only on application's exit.
                // Hence `translator` will outlive the application, there is
                // no need to worry about it.
}
```